# ValueError: 'penguin classifier/' is not a valid root scope name

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use penguin dataset just like https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#setup tutorial.

One change I've made is the training, instead of custom training I've built model using functional api and compiled it for training. Here is the code:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,))
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(inputs)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(dense)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(dense)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="penguin classifier")
metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)

model.compile(loss=loss_fn, 
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=metrics)
```

Now when I try to fit the model `model.fit(ds_train)` it outputs following error

```
ValueError: 'penguin classifier/' is not a valid root scope name. A root scope name has to match the following pattern: ^[A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\\/>-]*$
```

When I train using custom training loops that is, using gradientTape it works fine. What is the reason for this?

Comment: use names that do not have spaces, you can use underscores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid scope name should match with the following regular expression:

```
 ^[A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\\/>-]*$
```

Please use any of these in the name like below instead of space : _ - . > /

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="penguin.classifier")
```